# Installing packages on Guix: How to specify a specific platform/system?

Tags: software-installation, guix

On Guix, I can install the `hello` package like this:

```
$ guix package -i hello
```

I can see that this package is available in different architectures:

```
$ guix package --show=hello
[...]
systems: x86_64-linux i686-linux armhf-linux aarch64-linux mips64el-linux
[...]
```

How can I install the `hello` package for a specific platform/system, say `i686-linux`?

Answer (score 4):

`guix install` itself doesn't know about architecture, but there's a trick. You can pass a package name to `guix install`, but also a store path directly. Using `guix build`, you can obtain the store path of the `i686-linux` variant of the package, like this:

```
guix build hello -s i686-linux
```

Then, you can install that, and as a one-liner:

```
guix install $(guix build hello -s i686-linux)
```